# Warp effect in flash AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, skew

I am looking for photoshop like warp effect, where an image is not rotated, but lets say the top two points(corners) are shifted, anyone would have any idea how to do that?

or an idea how to shift those two points to the left without moving whole image with skew, current code i'm using

```
function skewer(target:DisplayObject, _x:Number, _y:Number):void {
var mtx:Matrix = new Matrix();    
mtx.b = _y * Math.PI/180;     
mtx.c = _x * Math.PI/180;     
mtx.concat(target.transform.matrix);     
target.transform.matrix = mtx;
```

}

Tried googling a fair bit, the image is loaded in with a loader.

Thanks,
S

Comment: I'm not sure, but DisplacementMapFilter might do the trick...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great tutorial (with source code) on achieving that effect on flashandmath.com.
http://www.flashandmath.com/advanced/p10triangles/method.html

It gives an effect a bit like this:
[image]

I also have a different type of warp effect on my blog. I like to call it the "toilet bowl" effect :-)
http://plasticsturgeon.com/2011/03/cool-warp-transition-effect-for-text-or-images/

It takes an image and applies two pixelbender shaders to apply a ripple effect and a twirl. Full source code is also provided.

Comment: Thank you, but i'm rather novice in AS, that tutorial looked like what I need but got me nowhere when I tried it, I'm currently loading in the image remotely and putting it into MC(its several images in an array), how would I go about transforming them after that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you could try using (or creating your own) Pixel Bender shader.  [this](http://www.dasprinzip.com/pExamples/p83.html) is just a quick example i found by googling "*pixel bender warp*".  it's not at all what you are looking for, but i wanted to show you what's possible - assuming you didn't already know. pixel bender shaders are just filters and do no require animation.

more here:  [Working with Pixel Bender shaders](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS3E659D01-10C0-479d-8175-B40950BBC223.html)